# iterate over POJO properties and set it to another object

Tags: java, hibernate, rtti, pojo

In our application I have a routine that manually iterates over the properties of an POJO loaded by Hibernate and assigns those properties to a new instance of that object and then saves it.

e.g

```
Class TestClass{
    Integer a;
    String b;

    public void setA(Integer a){
        this.a = a;
    }
    public Integer getA(){
        return a;
    }
    ...
}
```

in the action it does

```
TestClass objectOne = testDao.get(id);
TestClass objectTwo = new TestClass();
```

and then the iteration is like

```
objectOne.setA(objectTwo.getA());
objectOne.setB(objectTwo.getB());
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to iterate through each propertie of **objectOne** and set it to **ObjectTwo**, because in our real application those objects have around 20 properties or so.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Check out the [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) lib. There you can use [`copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Will this copy the id too? my interest to be able to _persist_ a new object to the **DB**.

Comment: Is there a hibernate equivalent that also checks for uninitialized properties?, so that no lazy loading exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use reflection to do that in a loop if you don;t want to use the commons library, although using tried and tested code seem to be the wiser choice if you don't have a problem with adding the library to your existing application.

Edit:

This should be enough for you

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Although I don't know about the performance of this solution vs ApacheCommons I don't think there will be a huge difference.

Comment: I posted the link for the java reflection tutorial it should be enough for you... If you have trouble let me know!

Comment: @Thihara The link is no longer relevant. To keep this answer relevant, can an example be provided or the link updated?